# c# double modulus returns 0 with "Optimize Code" turned on

Tags: c#, double, jit, angle, modulo

So I made my own struct to represent angle values, with some convenience methods. However, while it works in Debug mode, when turning on optimizations in Release mode, my code behaves differently. Am I missing something? Does something change when it's jitted? It's a .NET 3.5 project in VS2010.

Basically I do the following:

```
    Func<double, double> FromDegrees = degrees => degrees*Math.PI/180;
    double Value = FromDegrees(9);
    double period = Math.PI*2;
    double newAngle = (Value % period + period) % period;
    // newAngle is 0!
```

A more complete example:

```
public struct Angle
{
    public readonly double Value;

    public const double AngularTolerance = 0.001; // 0.06 degrees
    public static readonly Angle FullRotation = (Angle) (Math.PI*2);

    public Angle(double angle)
    {
        Value = angle;
    }

    public static Angle FromDegree(double degrees)
    {
        return (Angle) (degrees*Math.PI/180);
    }

    public Angle NormalizeRotation(Angle? period = null)
    {
        period = period ?? FullRotation;
        var newAngle = (Angle)((Value % period + period) % period);
        //Console.WriteLine("Value=" + Value + ", Value % period="+(Value % period) + ", Value % period + period="+(Value % period + period)+", (Value % period + period) % period="+((Value % period + period) % period) + ", newAngle == period:"+(newAngle == period));

        //if (newAngle == period)
        //    newAngle = (Angle) 0;
        return newAngle;
    }

    public bool EqivalentRotation(Angle angle, Angle? period = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EqivalentRotation: Value=" + Value + ", other angle=" + angle.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("EqivalentRotation2: norm(Value)=" + NormalizeRotation(period).Value + ", other norm(angle)=" + angle.NormalizeRotation(period).Value);
        return angle.NormalizeRotation(period) == NormalizeRotation(period);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Angle a, Angle b)
    {
        return Math.Abs(a.Value - b.Value) < AngularTolerance;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Angle a, Angle b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public static implicit operator double(Angle length)
    {
        return length.Value;
    }

    public static explicit operator Angle(double length)
    {
        return new Angle(length);
    }
}
```

Calling EquivalentRotation as:

```
Angle.FromDegree(180).EqivalentRotation(Angle.FromDegree(9))
```

I get the output

```
EqivalentRotation: Value=3,14159265358979, other angle=0,15707963267949
EqivalentRotation2: norm(Value)=0, other norm(angle)=0
```

and it returns `false`.

Also, if I uncomment the `WriteLine` in ´NormalizeRotation` it works as expected.

Edit: Forgot to mention, this runs as a plugin inside another application, with which it communicates via COM.

Edit2: It seems like it won't occur if I launch it via Visual Studio, or if I immediately attach to the process after launching it (rather I'd have to attach to it after a while).

Edit3: Seems like this avoids the problem, for some reason... Is it just luck, or because it doesn't use implicit conversion?

```
        var periodValue = period.Value;
        var newAngle = (iAngle)((Value % periodValue + periodValue) % periodValue);
```

Comment: Please narrow it down to the smallest but complete program, something others can copy/paste and run. The first snippet is almost there but eliminate the FromDegrees.  (I can't get `newAngle == 0`)

Comment: Yes, please post a compilable example that exhibits the problem, preferably with what you expect expressed in the form of a `Trace.Assert(some condition you expect to be true)` statement.

Comment: Haven't been able to do that unfortunately, too Heisenbuggish.

Comment: Strange, works for me in Release mode as well

Comment: Does it make a difference in C# structs that in one place you're returning "return new Angle(length)" and in others you simply return a cast local "return (Angle) (degrees*Math.PI/180);" ?  In C++ that heisenburgerish behavior would be referring to defunct stack variables, i.e. returning a reference to a local.

Comment: I don't think so, structs are by-value. And actually, the second place calls that first place.

Comment: I cannot repro, but this is almost surely a jitter optimizer bug.  There's been a history of problem with structs.  They get heavily optimized to make good on the promise that structs are efficient and that code is not without problems.  A strategically placed [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] usually solves the issue.  Or just by keeping structs simple, like they were designed to be, and make it a class instead.